# What happened to "Restore Defaults" for Power settings in Ventura?

Tags: power-management, ventura

I just upgraded to Ventura and trying to get used to some of the changes. I see that the **Energy Saver** settings are no longer under the **Battery** section of System Settings and instead are now part of the **Lock Screen** section. No big deal, it was easy enough to find the new location, but I can't seem to find anywhere to restore system defaults anymore.

Before updating, I had temporarily set my MacBook to never shut off the display on battery and I would like to restore the default settings now but am not sure how anymore.

Comment: Came to post this question, saw yours. Looking for the same solution for the same story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing it from the Terminal?

```sh
sudo pmset restoredefaults
```

works for me :-)

Quoting bits from `man pmset` to provide some context:

> `pmset` manages power management settings such as idle sleep timing, wake on administrative access, automatic restart on power loss, etc.

Comment: It’s helpful if you provide some context around the `pmset` command like a link to the man page to further explain what it does.  Anyway, thank you for contributing and welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: That does the trick for me, thanks for the workaround!